# Free distance of given generator matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Given the generator matrix $$ G(z) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
z-1 & z-2 & 2z-3
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know the rate is 2/3 and that the convolutional code is of degree 1 over $F_5$.
What is not so clear to me is how to find the free distance.

I already considered the problem here: [Free distance of a convolutional code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304253/free-distance-of-a-convolutional-code)
but unfortunately, I don't understand how they got the free distance 5 in their exercice...

So I'd appreciate any comprehensible answer!

Comment: How much theory of polynomial generator matrices have you covered? Can you tell at a glance that this generator matrix has all those nice properties: *polynomial output implies polynomial input", "predictable degree" and such? Using those you can get a proof. You could also use the transfer functions and resulting enumerators. Or, simply run the usual variant of Viterbi algorithm on the trellis to calculate the free distance? This generator matrix is very simple, so it may well be that you are expected to simply do a case-by-case analysis.

Comment: Like, have you done the standard binary code with $G(z)=(1+z^2,1+z+z^2)$ as an example?